# recursively unload data from redshift to S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to recursively unload data from redshift into S3 bucket in different folder for each run. Is there a way to do this from redshift unload command ?

unload ('select * from venue')
to 's3://mybucket/tickit/venue_' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole'
manifest;

I want s3 bucket to have this sub folders :

s3://mybucket/tickit/venue_12/venue_0000_part_00 
s3://mybucket/tickit/venue_21/venue_0000_part_00 
s3://mybucket/tickit/venue_34/venue_0000_part_00

this venue_* where * is out from select query in unload command

Answer (score 0):

you have to design a metadata table with list of tables and add condition if required in metadata table.
1. with help of python/other scripting language read meta data and execute unload command for respective tables with specific buckets (generally tablename as bucketname or any other format you prefer)
2. Execute above code to unload data to respective buckets

Answer (score 0):

Using a python script running on an EC2 instance or anywhere else, you can achieve that.

For example, if you want to export every new 10000 rows of data, you can add that to you `UNLOAD` query, and keep track of the current **offset** to be unloaded using the Python program.

```
unload ('select * from venue WHERE ID > offset and ID < offset+10000') to 's3://mybucket/tickit/venue_' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole' manifest;
```

And execute the above query in desired intervals, and store the data in desired filename/file path.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Can we run a query and based on the output value create individual file directly without script ?  
s3://mybucket/tickit/venue_1/venue_0000_part_01.csv s3://mybucket/tickit/venue_1/venue_0000_part_02.csv s3://mybucket/tickit/venue_1/venue_0000_part_03.csv

Comment: You can set the name of the output file whatever you want in the SQL query itself. So yes, you can do that. 
Please upvote the answer and mark it as accepted  if it answers your question. Thanks